# How to create a living style guide with your own UI

Tags: angularjs, sass, copy-paste

I have created an website/application using Angular2. The infrastructure is all set, I have routing completed, sass being processed etc.

I have sections (components) on this website that will display current web standards for our designs (buttons, forms, copy). The purpose of this site is to give our developers a copy/paste solution for markup and sass.

We will most likely create our own css library but they will still need a good visual reference of what each class does and a copy/paste solution.

I know how to develop all the standards, what I don't know how to do is have the DOM display options for the user to copy/paste the code. I could manually enter the code into  or  tags but this will be hard to maintain and not very clean approach. I'd like to find some solution that will utilize my code and create these tags at run time.

Googling this question leads down the road of using living style guide generators, which i don't want to use... why? I like having the functionality of controlling my own layout and scaling my standards as I see fit with our own technology.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring this even further I ended circling yet again on documentation tools (KSS) where I would need to rebuild my entire style guide for this functionality using markdown and or JDOCs.

Solution!

Use CodePen, its free to signup however there are some nice to have features for a monthly fee. I easily created my code here using SASS, HTML and CSS libraries. CodePen has a great EMBED feature whereas I could copy/paste html or iframe right to my styleguide.

Problem is now solved, and we have have a dynamic Web & UI Styleguide.

Hope this method helps others in my situation.